# Formula for surface area with respect to x or y. Why is the radius for both y?

Tags: integration

I am reading this text in the stewart text:

[image]

and I'm wondering if the text here is correct. For (6), why is it $2\pi*y$ and not $2 \pi x$? Isn't x rotated around the y axis since it's a function of y? I guess that's not true since just because a function is a function of y doesn't mean x is the radius right? And we use $$\frac{dx}{dy}$$ in 6 because that's what the function's derivative is since the function is written as a function of y right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the text shown has a typo in equation 6; it should read $2\pi x$ rather than $2\pi y$.

Comment: do others agree??? Or am I wrong for thinking this?

Comment: I think I misunderstood something about what limits of integration to use... if the arc length formula that I use uses dy, then the limits of integration have to be for y. Conversely, if the arc length formula I use uses dx, then the limits have to be for x right?